# Eclipse can't render Android layout

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, render

Eclipse gives the following error when I try to add "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log) See the Error 
Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

Layout rendering error